# How to override padding-left into angular component within component

Tags: css, angular, responsive, padding, footer

I am trying to override the padding-left property of .container-fluid

```
    container-fluid {
    padding-right: 16px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    }
```

> .container-fluid class is present in parent component "detail-component.ts"

Trying to replace it using .normal-footer class

```
    {
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    margin-left: -16px !important;
    }
```

> .normal-footer class is present in child component "app-footer.ts"

I have added that app-footer.ts into detail-component.ts

I want to remove that space which is highlighted from left side

Thanks in Advance
Apologies in case of asking duplicate question.
Trying to add image but getting error.